# OpenCV KMeans (K-Means) python number of output clusters issue

Tags: python, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm using OpenCV's python interface to do K-Means clustering of
multidimensional data (usually dimension of 7). I'm getting strange
results for the clusters. When requesting n-clusters (index 0 to n)
some clusters don't have points assigned to them - which results in
less clusters than expected. Has someone successfully used the python
K-Means implementation of OpenCV? Some user experience or advice would
be most helpful.

Here is a code snippet of my python implementation:

```
points = cv.CreateMat(dim1, dim2, cv.CV_32FC2)
clusters = cv.CreateMat(dim1, 1, cv.CV_32SC1)
for a in range(0,dim0):
   for b in range(0,dim1):
       for c in range(0,dim2):
           #print float(list[a*dim1*dim2 + b*dim2 + c])
           cv.Set2D( points, b, c, float(list[a*dim1*dim2 + b*dim2 + c]) )
cv.KMeans2(points, numClusters, clusters, (cv.CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + cv.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100000, 0.00000001), 50)

for d in range(0,dim1):
    f.write(str(int(clusters[d,0])))
    f.write(' ')
    f.write('\n')
```

Regards,

Stefan

Comment: I don't know cv, but: what's numClusters ? Is every point in some cluster ? Can you check a few points, distance to nearest < distances to other clusters ?

Comment: NumClusters is the desired number of clusters to generate. Every point ends up in some cluster. The problem is that some clusters are empty. Effectively this means that less than NumClusters clusters are generated.

Comment: what is the value of your numClusters -- 10, 100 -- and what are Npoints, Ndim ? Were you able to check a few points, can you try different numClusters / other parameters / initial centres ?

Comment: @Denis, currently I have 180 clusters. The dimension of my points is 7. There are 642 points as input. Haven't experimented with other another number of clusters so far. There is no way of defining initial centers.

Comment: with only 3-4 points per cluster, some are bound to be empty (if Poisson, ~ 3 % empty + 10 % singletons). Guess you can only try Ncluster 190 200 ... until 180 come out :(

Answer (score 0):

This can be a desirable property, and it varies from implementation to implementation.

***How this happens***: When initialized randomly or when using Lloyd iterations, it may well happen that a cluster loses all its objects. In MacQueen k-means it should always keep at least one object. Assume that in 1d, there are (among others) objects at 1 and 2, assigned to cluster c1. The cluster c1 has a mean of 1.5. Now if there are two other clusters whose mean move to 0.6 and 2.4, then these two objects will be reassigned, and the cluster c1 will suddenly become empty.

***Why this may be desirable***: assuming you don't know the best value for `k` beforehand, you might just decide to choose a too large k and see if some of the clusters degenerate.

Most likely this does however indicate that your data set just does not work with k-means. K-means is actually pretty picky, it is surprising how often it still works satisfactory enough. In general, k-means does not like clusters that vary in size but a close to each other. Because k-means will always split in the middle! Plus, in your particular case, `k` is probably *way* too high.

Here's a one dimensional illustration of a situation which k-means does not like: (A and B are object of their clusters; the second line indicates the true means and the middle split between the two means. k-means would then reassign and split even further to the left.

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBB
      A    |    B
```